# Which event gets called when I close a screen by clicking [X] red button of windows?

Tags: java, javafx, window

Is there any event handler present in Java FX, if I close a window directly by pressing [X] button on Top right side? Which events gets fired in this case? Nothing is working so far, neither `setOnHiding` not `setOnCloseRequest()`
What I want is, When I close (by clicking [X] button) showLogin Screen, showSplashScreen should also gets closed.

Please help.

Attaching my code here.

```
@Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

      ....
      ......
      .......
        this.primaryStage = primaryStage;
        if (userCredentials == null) {
            showSplashScreen();
            showLoginScreen();
        } else {
            showAppointmentScreen();
        }
    }


private void showSplashScreen(){
        primaryStageSplash = new Stage();

        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/fxml/SplashScreen.fxml"), bundle);
        primaryStageSplash.setResizable(false);
        primaryStageSplash.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);
        primaryStageSplash.centerOnScreen(); // center on screen
        fxmlLoader.setControllerFactory(paramClass -> context.getBean(paramClass));

        try {
            BorderPane root = new BorderPane(fxmlLoader.load());
            scene = new Scene(root, 445, 299);
            //scene.getStylesheets().add(DeliveryManager.class.getResource("/css/main.css").toExternalForm());
            primaryStageSplash.setScene(scene);
            primaryStageSplash.show();

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            errorHandler.escalateCriticalFailure(ex);
        }
    }


private void showLoginScreen() {
        primaryStage = new Stage();

        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/fxml/LoginForm.fxml"), bundle);
        primaryStage.setMaxHeight(125.0);
        primaryStage.setMaxWidth(255.0);
        primaryStage.setResizable(false);
        primaryStage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);
        primaryStage.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
        primaryStage.centerOnScreen(); // center on screen
        //Set the title from the resources.
        primaryStage.setTitle((String) bundle.getObject("UserInterface.LoginForm.Label.Title"));

        fxmlLoader.setControllerFactory(paramClass -> context.getBean(paramClass));

        if(operatingMode.equals(OperatingMode.REPRINT)) {
            primaryStage.getIcons().add(new Image("/images/reprint_utility_icon.png"));
        }
        else {
            primaryStage.getIcons().add(new Image("/images/delivery_manager_icon.png"));
        }

        try {
            BorderPane root = new BorderPane(fxmlLoader.load());
            scene = new Scene(root, 270, 180);
            root.setOnMousePressed(new MousePressHandler());
            root.setOnMouseDragged(new MouseDragHandler());
            scene.getStylesheets().add(DeliveryManager.class.getResource("/css/main.css").toExternalForm());
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            errorHandler.escalateCriticalFailure(ex);
        }
    }



@Override
    public void stop(){
        Event event = new Event(null, primaryStage,null);
        ((Node)(event.getSource())).getScene().getWindow().hide();

        event = new Event(null, primaryStageSplash,null);
        ((Node)(event.getSource())).getScene().getWindow().hide();
        //primaryStageSplash.close();
    }
```

`

Comment: [WindowEvent](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/WindowEvent.html) is fired, when you click on the X on the window icons. You can get the Window from your Scene with `scene.getWindow()` have a look at the [Scene](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Scene.html#getWindow--) class

Comment: The `onHidden` handler will get invoked whenever the window is closed (however it is closed). The `onCloseRequest` handler will get invoked whenever there is an *external* call to close the window, such as the user clicking on the OS-level close button. (Your login stage doesn't have one of these, since you set the style to `UNDECORATED`.) If these don't work for you, you need to include your attempt to use them (i.e. provide a [MCVE]) in your posted code, otherwise no-one can possibly know what you are doing wrong.

Comment: Your `stop` method makes absolutely no sense, btw. You create two events with `null` as the event source, and then try to call `getSource()` on them. It's not even clear what the point of that method is: `stop()` is invoked when the application exits, so the windows will close anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, if you just want to close your popup `Stage` when the primary `Stage` is closed, you do not have to listen to any event, you can set the primary Stage as [owner](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/Stage.html#initOwner-javafx.stage.Window-) of your splash screen.

> A stage can optionally have an owner Window. When a window is a
>   stage's owner, it is said to be the parent of that stage. When a
>   parent window is closed, all its descendant windows are closed. The
>   same chained behavior applied for a parent window that is iconified. A
>   stage will always be on top of its parent window. The owner must be
>   initialized before the stage is made visible.

```
primaryStageSplash.initOwner(primaryStage);
```

The only drawback is, that the child window will always be on top its parent window. If it is a problem for you, you can still listen to the changes of the [onCloseRequestProperty](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/Window.html#onCloseRequestProperty) of your primary Stage.

> Called when there is an external request to close this Window.

```
primaryStage.setOnCloseRequest((e) -> {
    primaryStageSplash.close();
});
```

I know that you stated that it does not work, but it should work as it is the "official" way to detect external close request.

Comment: Thanks DVarga, But I have tried the same solution but it didn't work. I debug my application and found - When i am directly closing primaryStage screen, Screen gets closed but control is not reaching at code 

"primaryStage.setOnCloseRequest((e) -> {
    primaryStageSplash.close();
});"

After this i close primaryStageSplash screen, not control is reaching at this code.

Where i m doing wrong, i m not getting any idea.

Comment: Please update the question what you have tried (the full code please).

Comment: Now its working... dont know how. But its working. Thanks